# I want to create functions that take as parameter tables mysql

Tags: python, mysql-connector

## I want to create functions that takes as parametre tables mysql

> the code works when I put the table name in the select. However, I   wanted to use the function by putting the name of the SQL table as a parameter but as I did the AC not working

```
def max_index  (con,tableau)  :
con.execute("SELECT max(indexes) FROM table_name%s",(tableau))
max_id = con.fetchone()[0]
return max_id 

def recupere_espece(cursor,maxid,tab2):
cursor.execute("""SELECT espece  FROM tab2 WHERE indexes=%s""",      (maxid,))
es=cursor.fetchone()[0]

es.split()
return int(es[2])
```

Comment: In the first `SELECT` don't you just want `... FROM %s", (tableau)`

Comment: @jcfollower i am tring but it is not working

Comment: Is there an error message?